# I have to rename all file names with first word of their content in unix

Tags: file, unix, command, rename

I used this

```
head -1 -q *.txt|awk '{print $1}'
```

which prints first line of the content in a file.
Now how to proceed with renaming the files?

Comment: Do you want to handle the case where the names clash?

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
for fname in *.txt
do
mv $fname $(head -1 -q $fname|awk '{print $1}')
done
```

Comment: No need to pipe `head` to `awk`.  `awk '{print $1; exit}'` works.  Also, `-q` is a non-standard option to `head`.